# Trigger is invalid and failed re-validation error while inserting records

Tags: java, oracle

I have table like this with trigger and sequence:

```
  CREATE TABLE "RTH"."TBL_USER" 
   (    "USR_ID" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USR_IS_ANONYMOUS" RAW(1), 
    "USR_FIRST_NAME" CLOB, 
    "USR_MID_NAME" CLOB, 
    "USR_LST_NAME" CLOB, 
    "USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL" CLOB, 
    "USR_ALT_EMAIL" CLOB, 
    "USR_PRIMARY_CNCT_NMBR" CLOB, 
    "USR_SECONDARY_CNCT_NMBR" CLOB, 
    "USR_TYPE" CLOB, 
    "USR_CATEGORY" CLOB, 
    "USR_DOB" TIMESTAMP (0), 
    "USR_CREATE_DT" TIMESTAMP (0), 
    "CUPN_ID" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "USR_MARITIAL_STUTUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "USR_GENDER" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "USR_IMAGE" RAW(1), 
    "USR_PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "XPKTBL_USER" PRIMARY KEY ("USR_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
 LOB ("USR_FIRST_NAME") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_MID_NAME") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_LST_NAME") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_ALT_EMAIL") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_PRIMARY_CNCT_NMBR") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_SECONDARY_CNCT_NMBR") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_TYPE") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) 
 LOB ("USR_CATEGORY") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING ) ;


  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "RTH"."TBL_USER_TRIGGER" 
BEFORE INSERT ON TBL_USER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT TBL_USER_SEQ.nextval
INTO :new.USR_ID
FROM dual;
END;

ALTER TRIGGER "RTH"."TBL_USER_TRIGGER" ENABLE
/
ALTER TRIGGER "RTH"."TBL_USER_TRIGGER" ENABLE;
```

When I try to insert a record I get an error saying:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04098: trigger 'RTH.TBL_USER_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Java code for inserting records:

```
String query = "insert into TBL_USER(USR_FIRST_NAME,USR_LST_NAME,USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL,USR_PASSWORD) values(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

pst.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
pst.setString(2, user.getLastName());
pst.setString(3, user.getEmail());
pst.setString(4, user.getPassword());
pst.executeUpdate();
```

I tried looking online but couldn't find a solution for my error, most of the errors are related to oracle itself

**Update:** As suggested by @Durga Viswanath, running the query:

```
select * from all_sequences where sequence_name = 'TBL_USER_SEQ';
```

Gave the following results:

```
SEQUENCE_OWNER                 SEQUENCE_NAME                  MIN_VALUE              MAX_VALUE              INCREMENT_BY           CYCLE_FLAG ORDER_FLAG CACHE_SIZE             LAST_NUMBER            
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------- ---------------------- 
RTH                            TBL_USER_SEQ                   1                      9999999999999999999999999999 1                      N          N          100                    101                    

1 rows selected
```

Now I get a new error while inserting records:

```
One error saving changes to table "RTH"."TBL_USER":
Row 10: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "RTH.TBL_USER_TRIGGER", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RTH.TBL_USER_TRIGGER'
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Could you also post the table definition for `TBL_USER_SEQ` ?  Try using `SHOW ERRORS` after your trigger definition.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated the question

Comment: You need to go through errors and understand the meaning of those, error clearly says "character string buffer too small". I have edited my answer for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run like this to get the issues of your trigger. As per exception trigger is invalid.

```
SQL> alter trigger tbl_user_trigger compile;

Warning: Trigger altered with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for TRIGGER TBL_USER_TRIGGER:

<It will display errors here>
```

Also, you can run this query to confirm whether you have sequence or not. Syntactically your trigger code is correct.

```
select * from all_sequences where sequence_name = 'TBL_USER_SEQ';
```

Answering `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small`

You have `"USR_ID" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,` which means USR_ID can store only one character. Once usr_id crosses 9, it will throw the error. You need to change the data type of USR_ID.

Comment: Updated the question using your comments. I get a new error now please have a look

Comment: I have changed the ID column type to NUMBER. Now its working but I have a question here. The id is getting inserted as starting from 101.. Is it better to have it as BLOB or INTEGER type for ID column? What do you recommend? I am not very savvy with oracle

Comment: It should be integer as that field will not have decimals. Also mark as answered and up vote, if it helps in resolving the issue.

Comment: The ID's are not getting inserted in order?

Comment: That is separate question and you need to read further about sequences.